# Keyboard shortcut for switching between workspaces

Tags: linux, unix

Is there a keyboard shortcut that enables you to switch between workspaces in Linux in a similar way to switching between windows using **ALT+TAB**? The documentation on this is incomplete and it would be nice to use the keyboard for this instead of the mouse.

Comment: What environment are you talking about? The console? A graphical interface (which one)?

Comment: I am using SUSE, with Gnome. But I was looking for some sort of a "global" or "universal" shortcut.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

CTRL + ALT + LEFT_ARROW or CTRL + ALT + RIGHT_ARROW

CTRL + F# might also work, depends a bit
even CTRL + SHIFT + F# might be mapped for the ones above 12

Comment: see my comment for the original question

Comment: added CTRL to the key combinations